# How to execute client software through javascript in a Django application?

Tags: javascript, python, django

Im thinking about creating an asset management application in Django. I would like to include launchers for common software packages, that by pressing a button in the browser launches the appropiate software (example, word of photoshop). How would I go on about doing this?

Comment: Here's a similar question I once asked:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730301/interact-with-local-pc-from-webapp

Comment: I have seen it done, I just dont know how to do it. It is for use in an intranet with trusted aunthentified users only, obviously not over the internet.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible not using browser bugs, because such feature is really dangerous. Tip: any guarantees you will launch photoshop, not "format c:"???

Answer (score 1):

And why not launch `del c:\*.*` while you're at it? It's not possible for very good reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Client-side java script has 0 access to the client filesystem.